# Как обратиться к элементу объекта Typescript<Object> в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

В моем React компоненте есть useState которому я присвоил тип < Object >

```
const [isValid, setIsValid] = React.useState<Object>({
      username: { valid: false, error: '' },
      email: { valid: false, error: '' },
      password: { valid: false, error: '' },
    });
```

Но я не могу обратиться к элементу объекта, например:

```
isValid.username
```

Выдаёт ошибку: Свойство "username" не существует в типе "Object"

Как обратиться к элементу объекта?

Comment: а если упустить <Object>?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно описать тип так, чтобы в нем были все свойства:

```
type StateItemType = {
  valid: boolean;
  error: string;
};

type StateType = {
  username: StateItemType;
  email: StateItemType;
  password: StateItemType;
};

const [isValid, setIsValid] = React.useState<StateType>({
  username: { valid: false, error: '' },
  email: { valid: false, error: '' },
  password: { valid: false, error: '' },
});
```

Тип Object для описания стейта в данном случае не подойдет.